# Select helper not showing fields values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-helpers

I'm trying to build a form with select. I want the select to show the users name and map it the id of their db record. there trouble I'm having is instead of showing the names as the options is how the object id

```
 #<User:0x007fac10de06c0>
```

this is the code is have used for the select helper

```
select :task, :assigned_to , @project.team.users{|user| [user.profile.name, user.id]
```

Comment: Can you put the exact code on your view? With the `erb` tags and all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be `@project.team.users.collect`